# Move to a bookmark or specific page in pdf

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

I want to open a pdf file and move to a specific bookmark in a C++ and qt program. According to my research, we can go to a bookmark using URLs and command prompt. Using URL has special format like: fileName.pdf#page=3
It works in command prompt but dont work with the `system()` function in a C++ program.

The second method needs to determine the acrobat.exe installation directory but it is complicated to find the directory each time.

Is there simpler way? And why doesn't the first solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
CString params;
params.Format(_T("/A \"page=%d\" \"%s\"")
    , page
    , (LPCTSTR)pdf
    );
::ShellExecute(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetSafeHwnd(), _T("open"), pdf_reader, params, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

The 'pdf_reader' is the path to Acrobat.exe. I get this like:

```
CString  pdf_reader;
int hinst = (int)(::FindExecutable(pdf, NULL, pdf_reader.GetBuffer(1024)));
pdf_reader.ReleaseBuffer();
if(hinst > 32){

}
else{
    CString csmess = _T("Error encountered while trying to load the helpfile:");
    if(hinst == 0){
        csmess += _T("\nThe system is out of memory or resources.");
    }
    else if(hinst == 31){
        csmess += _T("\nThere is no association for pdf - file type.");
        csmess += _T("\nInstall Adobe Reader (R) first.");
    }
    else if(hinst == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
        csmess += _T("\nThe specified file was not found:");
        csmess += _T("\n") ;
        csmess += pdf;
    }
    else if(hinst == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND){
        csmess += _T("\nThe specified path was not found.");
    }
    else if(hinst == ERROR_BAD_FORMAT){
        csmess += _T("\nThe .exe file is invalid (non-Win32 .exe or error in .exe image).");
    }
    else{
        csmess += _T("\nError encountered in FindExecutable.");
    }
    AfxMessageBox(csmess);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Please format the code, this is not Yahoo! Answers.

Comment: @KungPhoo thanks for your quick reply. But what is pdf_reader? if it is the directory of a pdf reader application, it's exactly my problem to find the directory each time in different systems.

Comment: I have another problem now. If the pdf file has been opened before, I can't go to specific page with this command. In fact, the page in opened file doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)

It's a well documented library for rendering pdf that supports Qt 4/5 platform.
Going to a specific page and moving on bookmarks are done by calling member functions.

Comment: I read documentations.It's not exactly what I want. Thanks anyway